# C++ Guessing Game

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main();
void Menu();
void PlayGame();
void Again();

int main()
{
// Seed the random number generator
srand(time(0));
Menu();
return 0;
}

// Menu so can keep playing or close the program
void Menu()
{
int selection = 0;
bool playing = true;

while (playing)
{
    cout << "Guess Number Game\n\n";
    cout << "Menu\n\n";
    cout << "1) Play Game\n";
    cout << "2) Exit\n\n";
    cout << "Enter your selection: ";
    cin >> selection;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << endl;

    if (selection == 1)
       PlayGame();
    else if (selection == 2)
        playing = false;
    else if (selection != 1 || 2) //lets the user know why they are going        back to the menu
        cout << "Try again, choose 1 or 2" << endl;
  }

}


void PlayGame()
{
int RandomNumber = rand() % 50 + 1; // to set the random number between 1-50
int attempts = 15; // sets attempts at guessing the number to 15
int guess;
const int HighestNum = 50;
const int LowestNum = 1;

cout << "Guess the random number between 1 and 50!\n";

while (true)
{
    cout << "You have " << attempts << " attempts remaining\n\n"; // so the      user can keep track of attempts
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> guess;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << '\n';

    if (guess == RandomNumber)
    {
        cout << "Congratulations, you won: " << RandomNumber << "!";
        cout << "\n\n" << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to play again y or n?" << endl;
        cin.get ();
        void Again();
    }
    else if (guess < RandomNumber) // to satisfy requirements of showing user whether the guess is too low
    {
        cout << "That guess is too low!\n" << endl;
    }
    else if (guess > RandomNumber)// to satisfy requirements of showing user whether the guess is too high
    {
        cout << "That guess is too high!\n" << endl;
    }
    else if (guess > HighestNum || guess < LowestNum)
    {
        cout << "Guess must be lower than 50 and higher than 1, Try again"     << endl; //setup so guesses not within the range of 1-50 do not count against the 15 guesses
        cin.get();//remove this to count guesses that are outside the 1-50
    }
    attempts--;

    if (attempts == 0)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, no guesses remain. The random number was... " <<     RandomNumber << "!";//so the user can see the random number at the end of their attempts
        cout << "\n";
        cin.get();
        void Again();
    }
}
void Again();
{
int decision = 0;
bool TryAgain = true;
char y;
char Y;
char n;
char N;

while (TryAgain)
{
    cout << "Y) Play Again\n";
    cout << "N) Exit\n\n";
    cout << "Enter your selection: ";
    cin >> decision;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << endl;

    if (decision == y || decision == Y)
    {
       PlayGame();
    }
    else if (decision == n || decision == N)
    {
        TryAgain = false;
    }
    else if (decision != y, Y || n, N) //lets the user know why they are going back to the menu
    {
        cout << "Try again, choose y or n" << endl;
    }
}
return
```

Trying to get the `void Again ();` to read from the `void PlayGame();`. Using the void Again (); to ask the user if they want to play again. Please Help!

Could also use someone help to change the function to have the prototype int reviewGuess(int, int), where the function takes the random number generated by the computer as the first parameter and the number guessed by the user as the second parameter.

- If the numbers match, the function will return a value of zero.
- If the number is too high, the function will return a value of 1.
- If the number is too low, the function will return a value of -1.

Rather confused ATM.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you should fix the issues which Alde has mentioned. Next off what's up with the `while (true)` statement? You should probably replace it with `while (attempts != 0)` and set the:

```
if (attempts == 0) {
    cout << "Sorry, no guesses remain. The random number was... " << RandomNumber 
        << "!";//so the user can see the random number at the end of their attempts
    cout << "\n";
    cin.get();
    void Again();
}
```

out of the while scope.

And about your `int reviewGuess(int, int)` function,are you looking for something like this:

```
int reviewGuess(int randomNumber,int userChoice)
{
    if(randomNumber == userChoice)
       return 0;
    if(userChoice > 50)
       return 1;
    if(userChoice < 1)
       return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I need the int reviewGuess(int, int) to get return those values then include a switch statement to give the response for each of the values. Basically, the return 0 would have to = "You win!!"   1 "Your choice is higher than randomNumber"  -1 "Your choice is lower than randomNumber"

Comment: but had trouble with integration                                                                                                           
   int reviewGuess(int randomNumber,int userChoice)
{
Int x
    if(randomNumber == userChoice)
       x = 0;
    if(randomNumber >  userChoice )
       x = 1;
    if(randomNumber < userChoice )
       x = -1;
switch (x)
{
case 1:
  x = 0
 cout << “You Win!!” << endl;
Case 2:
  x = 1
 cout << “The number is higher ” << endl;
Case 3:
  x = -1
 cout << “The number is lower” <<endl;
default:
 cout << “The number must be between 1 – 50” << endl;
}
Return x
}

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues:

- you are missing a ending '}' at the end of PlayGame and Again functions
- in the latter one the return is optional and should have a ';' at the end
- you are comparing 'decision' with unitialized variables y, Y, n, and N... I guess you wanted compare its value with the chars 'y', 'Y', 'n', 'N'
- the 'else if (decision != y, Y || n, N)' is not a valid syntax and you are already in that case with just an 'else'
- you have an extra ';' at the end of 'void Again()'
- you are trying to call a function with 'void PlayGame();'
- the path the program is taking is not clean and you're doing unwanted recursion, it would be better to return a value instead

I would have done something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


void PlayGame()
{
    const int HighestNum = 50;
    const int LowestNum = 1;
    int RandomNumber = LowestNum + rand() % HighestNum;

    cout << "Guess the random number between " << LowestNum << " and " << HighestNum << "!\n\n";

    int attempts = 15;
    while (attempts > 0)
    {
        int guess;
        cout << "You have " << attempts << " attempt" << (attempts > 1 ? "s" : "") << " remaining\n";

        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> guess;
        cout << endl;

        if (guess < LowestNum || guess > HighestNum)
        {
            cout << "Guess must be higher than " << LowestNum << " and be lower than " << HighestNum << ". Try again!\n"  << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (guess == RandomNumber)
        {
            cout << "Congratulations, you won!\n\n"  << endl;
            return;
        }
        else if (guess < RandomNumber)
        {
            cout << "That guess is too low!\n" << endl;
        }
        else if (guess > RandomNumber)
        {
            cout << "That guess is too high!\n" << endl;
        }

        --attempts;
    }

    cout << "Sorry, no guesses remain. The random number was... " << RandomNumber << "!\n\n";
}

bool Menu()
{
    cout << "Guess Number Game\n\n";

    cout << "Menu\n\n";

    cout << "1) Play Game\n";
    cout << "2) Exit\n\n";

    cout << "Enter your selection: ";
    int selection = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        cin >> selection;
        cout << endl;

        if (selection == 1)
            return true;
        else if (selection == 2)
            return false;
        else
            cout << "Try again, choose 1 or 2: ";
    }
}

bool Again()
{
    cout << "1) Play Again\n";
    cout << "2) Exit\n\n";

    cout << "Enter your selection: ";
    int selection = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        cin >> selection;
        cout << endl;

        if (selection == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (selection == 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Try again, choose 1 or 2: ";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    bool play = Menu();
    if (play)
    while (true)
    {
        PlayGame();

        if (!Again())
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, using the menu setup to play again makes a lot more sense. I was not sure if I could call a void function within a void. I just started learning about the various types of functions. Thank you again.